# How to add Link to Story via VersionOne REST API?

Tags: api, rest, versionone

I'm able to create new Story via `POST` to `/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story` with corresponding XML payload. Setting all attributes (including relational) works like a charm. However I'm unable to figure out how to add a `Link` asset to the `Story` asset.

When I try `POST`ing to `/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Link` with following XML payload:

```xml
<Asset href='/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/New/Link'>
  <Attribute name='AssetType' act='set'>Link</Attribute>
  <Relation name='Asset' act='set'>
    <Asset href='/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Story/123' idref='Story:123'/>
  </Relation>
  <Attribute name='OnMenu' act='set'>true</Attribute>
  <Attribute name='URL' act='set'>http://my.example.com</Attribute>
  <Attribute name='Name' act='set'>My Link Title</Attribute>
</Asset>
```

The server however returns:

```xml
<Error href="/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Link">
  <Message>Violation'Readonly'Link.AssetType</Message>
  <Exception class="VersionOne.DataException">
      <Message>Violation'Readonly'Link.AssetType</Message>
  </Exception>
</Error>
```

Seems like adding links is prohibited but actually I can add `Link`s via the standard web interface without issues.

My original idea was to create `Link` asset first and then update the `Story` with respective relational attribute pointing to that `Link` asset.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!
(I'm using `JavaScript/jQuery`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. The `<Attribute name='AssetType' act='set'>Link</Attribute>` attribute in the `POST` payload is obviously wrong - it is trying to set the asset's type (link) which does not make sense since I'm stating the type in `URL` already. It works perfectly without the attribute (as expected).

Comment: How did you solved this, I need to update link using .net sdk, can you please let me know